# If I travel to Osaka, Tokyo Feb 1-10, can I view plants and nature?

Tags: discussion

Why [If I travel to Osaka, Tokyo Feb 1-10, can I view plants and nature?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151247/37866) closed off-topic? It undeniably is NOT **constructing travel and tour itineraries** because I already said I can go just to Osaka and Tokyo.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't do a review of this. If I had, I would have voted to leave it open because your actual question (whether Japan has interesting flora at a particular time of year) is certainly something that strikes me as being on-topic.

That said, I'm pretty sure I can tell you why it was closed. Allow me to describe your question, copying its format and approximate lengths of each section:

> **Your question starts with some irrelevant information about an argument you had with your girlfriend.**
>
> **1. Then you tell us about how you don't like cold weather**
>
> **2. Then you tell us what your girlfriend likes to do on holiday, and complain that you don't like those things, but tell us that you like plants and luxury fruits. You try (for unclear reasons) to link to an article about a taste-test of one such fruit, but the link doesn't work.**
>
> Then you finally get to your actual question about whether Japan has interesting non-evergreen plants in February.

I've bolded all of the stuff that isn't your question. I believe that should illustrate quite clearly how people may miss your question.

If you want to know about Japanese winter flora, just ask about Japanese winter flora. Don't tell us about your domestic disputes, don't complain that winter is cold, and don't complain that your girlfriend likes shopping. Those things have absolutely no relevance to the question, and serve only to distract from it.

Comment: I did not close the question either and if you cut out all Chris H bolded I will vote to open. Right now it does not fit our site.